# How to show a div when I click on a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
const targetDiv = document.getElementById("weging");
const btn = document.getElementById("toggle");

btn.onclick = function() {
  if (targetDiv.style.display !== "none") {
    targetDiv.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    targetDiv.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
#cijfers {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="weging">
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
<button type="button" id="toggle">Volgende</button>
<div id="cijfers">
  <p>Hello2</p>
</div>
```

Hello guys, I have this litte part in my website. When I press the button I want to hide div 'weging' and show div 'cijfers'. The div 'weging' hides perfectly with this JS code, but how can I show the div 'cijfers'. If anyone can help me out I would appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```js
function showDiv() {
   document.getElementById('welcomeDiv').style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<div id="welcomeDiv"  style="display:none;" class="answer_list" > WELCOME</div>
<input type="button" name="answer" value="Show Div" onclick="showDiv()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It maybe easier to use CSS and a "hidden" class. Apply the class to `cijfers` initially, and then when the button is clicked toggle the class on both divs (using [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) and [`toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle)) so that class is removed from `cijfers`, and added to `weging`. Clicking the button again would do the opposite.

```js
// Cache all the elements
const weging = document.getElementById('weging');
const cijfers = document.getElementById('cijfers');
const btn = document.getElementById('toggle');

// A more modern way of adding an event listener
// to an element
btn.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

// Put the elements into an array, and then iterate
// over each toggling the "hidden" class on/off
function handleClick() {
  [weging, cijfers].forEach(div => {
    div.classList.toggle('hidden');
  });
}
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<button type="button" id="toggle">Volgende</button>
<div id="weging"><p>Hello</p></div>
<div id="cijfers" class="hidden"><p>Hello2</p></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should answer your question when the user clicks on the button it will change the div style to display block

```js
function showDiv() {
   document.getElementById('divContent').style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<div id="divContent"  style="display:none;" class="answer_list" > Some content</div>
<input type="button" name="answer" value="Show Div" onclick="showDiv()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to happen at the touch of a button, then you can do something like this:

```
const targetDiv = document.getElementById("weging");
const btn = document.getElementById("toggle");
const cij = document.getElementById("cijfers");

btn.onclick = function() {
  if (targetDiv.style.display !== "none") {
    targetDiv.style.display = "none";
    cij.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    targetDiv.style.display = "block";
    cij.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to show and hide the divs at the same time, you can do something like this

```
const wegingDiv = document.getElementById("weging");
const cijfersDiv=document.getElementById("cijfers");
const btn = document.getElementById("toggle");

const toogableDisplays=()=>{
 if (wegingDiv.style.display !== "none") {
    wegingDiv.style.display = "none";
    cijfersDiv.style.display="block";
  } else {
    wegingDiv.style.display = "block";
    cijfersDiv.style.display="none";
  }
}

btn.onclick = toogableDisplays();
//Styles
#cijfers {
  display: none;
}
//HTML
<div id="weging">
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
<button type="button" id="toggle">Volgende</button>
<div id="cijfers">
  <p>Hello2</p>
</div>
```